# Lowercase urls in .NET Core RC2

Tags: routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In .net 5 / MVC 6 RC1 we could force lowercase urls in routes with the following:

```
services.ConfigureRouting(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

How is this accomplished in RC2 / .net core 1.0 ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think that you're now looking for the [`.AddRouting`](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/e8ce0e752360a98871a4f4c08df8213b2e2a2e01/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/DependencyInjection/RoutingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L55) extension method instead. You "configure" the instance of the `RouteOptions` as part of the addition of the service:

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

**Update**

You can also call the following:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

I detailed some of the API changes in my blog post [here](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/).

Comment: Interesting, you can call             services.Configure<RouteOptions> options =>  {  options.LowercaseUrls = true; });

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply to the login redirect url, but that was the case in RC1 as well.

Comment: I came across this setting while researching for the requirement to make all urls lowercase. I just can't see a difference (.NET core 1.1 web api, swagger behind IIS). It still accepts case insenstivie URLs. Any hints what should change and how I can test it?